# How to access any field inside json in karate

Tags: karate

I am trying to access element from a json.

`json{"a":"b","c":["d","e"]}`

I tried below code but its not working for me

`get json.c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* json variableName = {a: b , c: [ d, e ]}
* print variableName.c
```

Note that you don't really need quotation marks or apostrophes in Karate.